# how to find the header file to be included for a library function in linux

Tags: c, linux

Given a function, let's say atoi, how can I find the header file I should include if I want to use this function ? I'm always get puzzled for that issue. If let me treat function like "atoi" as linux c api, I can put my question in another way as : Is a document for linux c api ?

Comment: See man <function> or info <function> and apropos <function> Where apropos gives you the manpage section to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Man pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_pages). Type `man atoi` (or, in general, `man <function>`) at your command prompt. It will give you usage information as well as a listing of which headers to include.

Man pages also document programs and commands (find, grep, cd, etc.). Sometimes you may run into a case where a program has the same name as a C function (e.g. write). In that case, you need to direct man to look in the correct section of the manual, section 2 for system calls and section 3 for library functions. You do this by inserting the section number between "man" and the command name: `man 2 write`. If you do not know whether a given function is a system call or a library function, try both.

You can learn more about manual pages by typing `man man`.

Comment: +1 Side note: on some platforms it's possible you'll need to install these packages (e.g. for ubuntu `manpages-posix-dev` (headers) and `manpages-dev` (functions))

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can search your system's /usr/include directory for occurrences of the function definition you're looking for.  This is especially useful for embedded or stripped-down linux systems that are missing man pages.

```
find /usr/include -name "*.h" -print | xargs grep "<function-you-are-looking-for>"
```

For example, if you do:

```
find /usr/include -name "*.h" -print | xargs grep atoi
```

You'll get back something like this:

```
/usr/include/stdlib.h:extern int atoi (__const char *__nptr)
```

The result contains both the header file name and the interface definition.

- Please note that your /usr/include directory might be elsewhere.

Comment: also note that many things are defined in system-specific, (and sometimes kernel-version-specific) private header files that are #include'd by the public headers files, so searching via grep will not alway get you the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a document for linux c api ?

Certainly. The documentation is available as *man pages*. Type `man <function>` in a terminal and enjoy. Which header file you need to include is usually shown at the top.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ctags and the vim editor and you have set up ctags to scan /usr/include then ctrl-] while you're on the function you want to find takes you to the headerfile!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following also

```
whereis <function name>
```

It will give the path name for the function. Then open the path using vim editor. Then using the "vim" editor you can see the header file.

Example

```
> whereis atoi 
   atoi: /usr/share/man/man3/atoi.3.gz

 > vim /usr/share/man/man3/atoi.3.gz

   ----------
   ----------
  .B #include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: As noted above overly complicated.